# How to add target=blank in js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, xml

Screenshot:

[image: ...]
<sub>(source: [freenetph.yn.lt](http://freenetph.yn.lt/other/Screenshot_2017-06-25-14-06-44-1.png))</sub>

I found this code for a random links on the 3rd party site (I forgot the name) and it looks so helpful to me but my problem is that, I want all those links will open in a new tab when it clicked. Anybody can help me? Im new to web development. Thanks in advance.

Comment: please post your code

Comment: Is there a reason you don't write target=blank in your html? And code of what you have already done would be appreciated.

Comment: I cant post code. I dont know how. Please see my screenshot. Thanks. http://freenetph.yn.lt/other/Screenshot_2017-06-25-14-06-44-1.png

Comment: To others who want to edit the post to show the image inline: I tried, but it is http: so it won't show...

Comment: @NelfoxCañete you can put code blocks in your question by simply indenting it with four spaces. Anyway: you should read the help before posting questions.

Comment: Im new to this site sir/madam. Just a minute ago after my registration but im always visiting this site to learn on how to code. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the code in the screenshot, do this although using `document.write` is not recommended:

```
document.write('<a href="' + data[0] + '" target="_blank">' + data[1] + '</a>');
```

Comment: The code works perfectly. Thanks a lot sir. I used it now. 

Comment: @NelfoxCañete, glad I could help :). Happy coding

Comment: Thank you for sharing 

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
    window.open('http://link.com', '_blank');
</script>
```

Comment: This code is working too but there is a few random links i wanted to open in a new tab. I knew already the target="_blank" on HTML and base target="_blank". What i want to know is in javascript. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

As you are new to development, Instead of putting single line solution, I have added Code in your snippet, please check solution below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var links = ["random/end1.html|Castle 1", "random/end2.html|Castle 2", "random/end3.html|Castle 3"];

    function init() {
      var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * links.length),
        data = links[r].split('|');
      var answer = document.getElementById('answer');
      //document.write("<a href=\""+data[0]+ "\" target=\"_blank\">" + data[1] + "</a>");
      answer.innerHTML = "<a href=\"" + data[0] + "\" target=\"_blank\">" + data[1] + "</a>";
    };
  </script>

</head>

<body onload="init()">
  <div id="answer"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Sir @TusharVaghela your code is more lighter than the other one but my question is; "Can I apply the code to a particular div?" I want to show off my links in one of the div in my page. I try to apply it to the div but its not working. Here's how I apply; <div onload="init()"></div>

Comment: I have update code in previous answer and now it's rendering answer in `answer` div. 
Apart from that, instead of using `document.write` I have used `innerHTML` of div, which is safer and proper method.

Comment: _If you think that what useful, please mark it as useful by up voting it._

Comment: I got this error message upon voting, "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."